# Brand new 22.04 LTS installation Named fails on startup

Tags: dns, bind

Installed 22.04 LTS and all went smoothly. I'm not a Linux expert but followed directions on installing services [by LinuxTechi](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-bind-9-dns-server-ubuntu-debian/).

Bind9/Named refuses to start and I get the following error. I have no idea what's causing it or how to fix it. If someone can point me in the right direction, I'm willing to do the research and reading.

--------------------ERROR-----------------

```
 named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-07 17:44:37 UTC; 46s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)

    Process: 3922821 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 25ms

Jul 07 17:44:37 cazserver systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 07 17:44:37 cazserver systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
Jul 07 17:44:37 cazserver systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 07 17:44:37 cazserver systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 07 17:44:37 cazserver systemd[1]: Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
```

--------------------END ERROR-------------------

Comment: Followed these directions but used my domain.local in place of theirs.
https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-bind-9-dns-server-ubuntu-debian/

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns

Comment: Thank you so much.. removed what I had and started over following the directions you posted. Between you and Pihhan I got it working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is likely caused by configuration error. Have you tried running `named-checkconf` command?

Use `journalctl -xeu named` to read longer details from named. There should be exact reason. If the configuration is correct, I would guess another service is already listening on port 53. Try `sudo ss -lnp | grep  :53`.

Comment: YOU GOT IT!  I ran named-checkconf and had 2 instructions for ACL "internals" and I commented them out and bind loads and runs now.
THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!